# efficient way of creating regular series c++

Tags: c++, time

I've got a txt file with comma delimiters in which each line contains information collected at a certain time. The format of a line is as follows:
timeinseconds, numericvar1, numericvar2

However, the information is not collected regularly in time. My idea is using `C++`:
Step 1. Create a regular series, timeinsecondsRegular, with desired (lower frequency) intervals 30 min, 1 hour, etc. 
Step 2. Pick the closest line in time, previous to the target date of the sequence, from the file: max(0, min(timeinsecondsRegular - timeinseconds)).
Step 3. Write the regular series to new file.

I was thinking of using `getline` but I've read it is not very efficient. My file has around 100.000 rows. What alternatives are out there?

Comment: 100,000 rows is not a big file, `getline` is probably fine.  Try it.